# Sprite Kit crash when running an action/loading an asset on only iPad Air and iPad mini with Retina

Tags: ios, ipad, air, 64-bit, sprite-kit

I'm getting crash reports which are coming from retina mini and iPad Air devices, but not iPhone 5S. It occurs in SpriteKit when someone taps on a sprite which is supposed to then make another show up on screen.

I'm not able to reproduce this on a non-A7 device so wondered if anyone can take a look at the crash log below and let me know what the crash may be caused by?

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xb000000c
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x39b30b66 objc_msgSend + 5
1   CoreUI                               0x3349bd0d -[CUIStructuredThemeStore renditionWithKey:] + 1050
2   CoreUI                               0x334a50af -[CUINamedImage _renditionForSpecificKey:] + 168
3   CoreUI                               0x334a50fd -[CUINamedImage image] + 18
4   UIKit                                0x31b2ec01 -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:] + 260
5   UIKit                                0x31b2eaf7 -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:] + 38
6   UIKit                                0x31b2eacd -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:idiom:subtype:] + 44
7   UIKit                                0x31b2ea9b -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:idiom:] + 46
8   UIKit                                0x31b75c45 +[UIImage imageNamed:inBundle:] + 56
9   SpriteKit                            0x319fde65 __26-[SKTexture loadImageData]_block_invoke + 1282
10  SpriteKit                            0x31a3798d SKSpinLockSync(int*, void ()() block_pointer) + 102
11  SpriteKit                            0x319fd8fd -[SKTexture loadImageData] + 300
12  SpriteKit                            0x31a007ef -[SKTexture size] + 42
13  SpriteKit                            0x31a21585 -[SKSpriteNode initWithTexture:] + 180
14  SpriteKit                            0x31a217e3 +[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:] + 146
15  White                                0x000c6037 -[EggsOnShelfScene useStrawToolOn:] (EggsOnShelfScene.m:546)
16  White                                0x000c4c9b -[EggsOnShelfScene useToolOnEgg:] (EggsOnShelfScene.m:400)
17  White                                0x000d0929 -[EggsOnShelfScene handleTapGesture:] (EggsOnShelfScene.m:1746)
18  UIKit                                0x31c99739 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 194
19  UIKit                                0x31b4418b -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 1138
20  UIKit                                0x31ecfd4f ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke + 44
21  UIKit                                0x31b0b5cf _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 216
22  UIKit                                0x31b09d33 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 296
23  UIKit                                0x31b429fd -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 772
24  UIKit                                0x31b423ab -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 666
25  UIKit                                0x31b17d79 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
26  UIKit                                0x31b16569 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7114
27  CoreFoundation                       0x2f359f1f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
28  CoreFoundation                       0x2f3593e7 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
29  CoreFoundation                       0x2f357bd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 628
30  CoreFoundation                       0x2f2c2471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
31  CoreFoundation                       0x2f2c2253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
32  GraphicsServices                     0x33fd02eb GSEventRunModal + 138
33  UIKit                                0x31b77845 UIApplicationMain + 1136
34  White                                0x000dcf27 main (main.m:8)
35  libdyld.dylib                        0x3a02eab7 start + 0
```

Here's the code I use to create the sprite that's being displayed when the other is tapped on. Again this doesn't happen on anything but A7 devices and not on iPhones. Additionally this same code snippet is used to do the exact same thing on other sprites and does not crash on those.

```
if ([touchedSprite.name isEqualToString:@"Sad"]) {
    // Create the crop node
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        cropNode.position = CGPointMake(touchedSprite.position.x - 120, CGRectGetMinY(self.view.frame));
    } else
        cropNode.position = CGPointMake(touchedSprite.position.x - 120 * IPHONERATIO, CGRectGetMinY(self.view.frame) - 20);


    SKSpriteNode *sadSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"SadSprite"]];
    [sadSprite setName:@"sadSprite"];
    [cropNode addChild:sadSprite];

    sadSprite.position = CGPointMake(sadSprite.position.x, sadSprite.position.y + sadSprite.size.height / 2);

    SKSpriteNode *maskedImage = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"SadSpriteMask"]];
    [cropNode setMaskNode:maskedImage];

    [self addChild:cropNode];

    NSArray *slurpSounds = @[@"sadSprite01.caf", @"sadSprite02.caf", @"sadSprite03.caf"];

    // Keep the sadSprite in the same position in relation to the egg
    [sadSprite runAction:[SKAction moveByX:0 y:-sadSprite.size.height duration:0.6]];

    // Move the sadSprite into position
    [cropNode runAction:[SKAction moveByX:0 y:sadSprite.size.height duration:0.6] completion:^{
        [cropNode runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:slurpSounds[self.toolSoundNumber] waitForCompletion:YES] completion:^{
            [sadSprite runAction:[SKAction moveByX:0 y:sadSprite.size.height duration:0.6] completion:^{
                [sadSprite removeFromParent];
            }];
            [cropNode runAction:[SKAction moveByX:0 y:-sadSprite.size.height duration:0.6] completion:^{
                [cropNode removeFromParent];
            }];
        }];
    }];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you debugged and stepped through so you can determine what line it crashes on ? Can you post the actual error you are getting ?

Comment: Also, can you rule out that this is a memory pressure related crash? Consider that iPad Retina images use about 4x the memory of the same image for iPhone Retina.

Comment: I don't have access to any A7 devices at the moment. It's running fine on other iPads and iPhones without crashing. Will have one tomorrow for testing and will feedback what I find out then.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I get this on the console: `Mar  3 16:48:17 iPad-Mini Testbed[206] <Error>: CGImageProviderCreate: invalid image provider size: 12 x 0.
Mar  3 16:48:17 iPad-Mini Testbed[206] <Error>: CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 12 x 0.
Unable to create image from csi bitmap data`. Not using SpriteKit, just `imageNamed:` and only happens with sliced images.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some trial and error I tracked this down to having a sliced image where the top, bottom, left or right slice has size 0. I'd say this is a bug on iOS. Try adding more padding to your image so that your slices don't touch the edges.

Comment: While this wasn't exactly the answer to my question it did point me to the issue and it was a size of the assets being loading being incorrect issues. Thanks

Comment: Note that you can also set the slicing in code using `[-resizableImageWithCapInsets:]` on UIImage, which does seem to work with 0 insets.

Comment: Hi, I have similar problem but I am not sure if I understand what is the solution. Could you please be more specific? Thanks