# ios8 UIImage imageNamed: crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, uiimage

I am getting a strange crash listed in crashlytics for `UIImage imageNamed:` method. This crash appears only on iOS8 and is a persistent issue for many users. Although, strangely I have not been able to reproduce the issue while testing.

Please refer the image of crash log from crashlytics.
[image]

I guess, this may have to do something with the internal working of `imageNamed:` method.

Comment: check your image name with case sensitive ".png" and ".PNG"

Comment: Without the referenced source code of your app, it is impossible to understand what you are doing and provide accurate possibilities.

Comment: Are you sure you're not sending a nil/NSNull to imageNamed?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, however mine are all on iOS 7 (7.0.5 and 7.0.6). You might want to update your question with this info. But I have no clue what the problem might be. @rounak's suggestion doesn't apply to me, since I'm passing a string literal inline so there's no way for `nil`.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146957/sprite-kit-crash-when-running-an-action-loading-an-asset-on-only-ipad-air-and-ip I did in fact have a `slice.right == 0` so it might be really the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue got resolved after I moved the `UIImage imageNamed:` method from background thread to main thread. Incidentally, this should always have given a run-time crash, because that method is supposed to run on main thread only(as all UIKit methods), but for some reason previous versions of iOS let it run. In iOS8 though it crashes more often, but not always.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I had this exact problem and was tearing my hair out trying to figure out what was going on. My app was using `[UIImage imageNamed:]` in a CGPatternCalback in `DrawRect`. Simply moved the UIImage reference to a manager and refer to that rather than creating a new UIImage each time.